# How do you make ::after part of css pentagon responsive?

Tags: html, css

I have created a form that is responsive but I cannot  get the :before and :after elements which make it look like a polygon to be responsive. I want to make it so the top and bottom triangles resize along with the form.

How would I fix this? code pen: 
https://codepen.io/coolblow/pen/rKEOEa

```
.form{
  flex:1;

}
form {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin: -10px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 50%;
 position: relative;
}

form::before {
  content: '';
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 20px solid transparent; 
  border-right: 20px solid transparent; 
  border-bottom: 20px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -20px;
}

form::after {
  content: '';
  width: 0; 
  height: 0;
  border-left: 120px solid transparent; 
  border-right: 120px solid transparent; 
  border-top: 70px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -70px;
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use background to create the whole shape:

```css
form {
  padding: 50px 20px;
  margin:20px;
  width:50%;
  height:200px;
  background:
    /*Top part*/
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 49%,green 50%)top right/50.5% 50px,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49%,green 50%)top left/50% 50px,
    /*middle part*/
    linear-gradient(green,green) center/100% calc(100% - 100px),
    /*bottom part*/
    linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 49%,green 50%)bottom right/50.5% 50px,
    linear-gradient(to top right,transparent 49%,green 50%)bottom left/50% 50px;  
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<form>
</form>
```

**Update**

If you want smaller triangle on the top you can do this:

```css
form {
  padding: 50px 20px;
  margin:20px;
  width:50%;
  height:200px;
  background:
    /*Top part*/
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 49%,green 50%)calc(50% + 25px) 0/50px 50px,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49%,green 50%)calc(50% - 25px) 0/50px 50px,
    /*middle part*/
    linear-gradient(green,green) center/100% calc(100% - 100px),
    /*bottom part*/
    linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 49%,green 50%)bottom right/50.5% 50px,
    linear-gradient(to top right,transparent 49%,green 50%)bottom left/50% 50px;  
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<form>
</form>
```

And for more control you can use CSS variables to adjust dimensions:

```css
form {
  margin:20px;
  width:50%;
  height:120px;
  --tw:50px; /*Top triangle*/
  --bw:50px; /*Bottom triangle*/
  padding: var(--tw) 20px var(--bw);
  background:
    /*Top part*/
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 49%,green 50%)calc(50% + var(--tw)/2) 0/var(--tw) var(--tw),
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49%,green 50%)calc(50% - var(--tw)/2) 0/var(--tw) var(--tw),
    /*middle part*/
    linear-gradient(green,green) 50% var(--tw)/100% calc(100% - (var(--tw) + var(--bw))),
    /*bottom part*/
    linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 49%,green 50%)bottom right/50.5% var(--bw),
    linear-gradient(to top right,transparent 49%,green 50%)bottom left/50% var(--bw);  
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<form>
</form>

<form style="--tw:80px;--bw:60px;">
</form>

<form style="--tw:120px;--bw:120px;">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! do you know how to make the top triangle smaller and center it? also where can i read more on this technique? thank you again

Comment: @csscrub check the update ;) this technique is the use of multiple background with gradient, so simply read about gradient : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Comment: Can you help me make the upper triangle smaller like I have in my code pen? I can't figure out how to resize it. anything i try makes a bunch of white space

Comment: @csscrub check my update again, added another snippet ;)

Comment: still dont understand but i adjusted your code to meet my requirments. I thought css would be easy lol this is all very tricky. thank you for your help tho.

Comment: Magnificent.  Truly.  I just got done doing some of this type of stuff with pseudo-elements and unnecessary additional markup.  Had never considered the idea of leveraging background!

Comment: @TemaniAfif  This method seems to break when i add my form input fields

Comment: @TemaniAfif Could you help me make a layout like this? https://imgur.com/a/NNMfyYI